# Deploying multiple angular6 applications to DigitalOcean using nginx

Tags: angular, tomcat, nginx, digital-ocean

I deployed my spring boot application to DigitalOcean. I created a war file then deployed it to tomcat server.

I have two angular6 applications for a bookstore website, one for admin portal and one for store part. I want to deploy these two apps to DigitalOcean and run them via different ports, namely 4200 and 4201.

I managed to run one with nginx, I uploaded output of "ng build" command to /var/www/html folder and it runs well with the tomcat server. But I couldn't succeed running it using nginx server configuration. Something like

```
server {  
  server_name localhost;
  listen 4200;
  root /var/www/frontend/src;

  try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

How can I deploy two angular applications to an Ubuntu droplet and run them synchronously with Tomcat server?